# Finding lacunary points of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

I understand that lacunary points are those which don't belong to the image of a function. For example, since $e^{z}$ can never assume value zero, it's lacunary point is $0$.  But I don't get why $i$ and $-i$ are lacunary points of $\tan z$ and $\cot z$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\, w := \exp(i z),\,$ then $\, \tan(z) = i (1-w^2)/(1+w^2)\,$ and  $\, \tan(z) = i\,$ implies $\, w = 0 \,$ but $\,\exp(z)\,$ is lacunary.